# MySQL Database Structure Push Values to One Field or Create New Table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm try to figure out the optimal database structure for a scenario where users belong to one organization and within the organization table there is a field with all of the emails of the users associated with that organization. Within the `users` table I have a foreign key of `organization_id` which passes the value of the organization that user is associated with, but on the `organization` table I'm currently was planning on creating a `members` column that would add the email address (comma separated) for each user that is associated with that organization. I plan on using this column for WHERE conditions in retrieving records. Is this the smart way to do it or should I create another table called `members` that associated both the `users` and `organization` table?

Here is my `organization` table:

```
CREATE TABLE `organization` (
  `organization_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `organization_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `admin` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `members` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `createdAt` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updatedAt` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`organization_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Here is my `user` table:

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `createdAt` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updatedAt` datetime NOT NULL,
  `organization_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: is this a many-to-many relationship? (can a user belong to multiple organizations?) if so, you might want to have a membership table that records all pairings of user_id with org_id, rather than have duplicated info in either of the parent tables.

Comment: A user can only belong to one organization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's a one-to-many (an organization has many users, but a user can only belong to one organization), I'd do a structure like this:

```
user
user_id    first_name  . . . email    org_id
---------------------------------------------
  (PK)                                 (FK)

organization
org_id     org_name . . . 
------------------------------
  (PK)
```

. . . which is what you have.

To get all members (and their emails or other info) of an organization:

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.email
FROM user u
WHERE org_id = (whatever value you want)
```

Inserting user_id or emails (or 'members') into the org table would be unnecessary duplication, since users are already linked to org's by the org_id. You can get an org mailing list from the above query.

I'd only do a members table if you had a many-to-many relationship.

If this is missing something, let me know, and I'll go back to the drawing board.

Comment: thank for this. What if I was inserting a value into the table. e.x. `organization.org_members` currently contains a value of `test@test.com` and then an insert happens that appends `test2@test.com` to the values that are already present, so `organization.org_members = test@test.com, test2@test.com`

Comment: i don't like having multiple values in a field - too much work later on. with org_id in the user table, you can pull all the emails (or whatever) for an org with the query above. edited answer to (hopefully) explain my thinking.

Comment: @cphill - glad to help!